# Setting PATH variable from inside makefile does not work for make 3.81

Tags: xcode, makefile, osx-mountain-lion

Change the environment variable `PATH' in Makefile does NOT take effect with make in CLT, and it's OK with the make util which I compiled from original source.

The simple Makefile

```
PATH := $(PATH):/opt/bin

export PATH

all:
      @cscope --version
```

My tests

```
/tmp $ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
/tmp $ ls /opt/bin/cscope
/opt/bin/cscope
/tmp $ which make
/usr/bin/make
/tmp $ make
make: cscope: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
/tmp $ ./_install/bin/make
cscope: version 15.7a
/tmp $ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
/tmp $ ./_install/bin/make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `cscope` the only tool you're worried about, or are the others in `/opt/bin/`?

Comment: No, it is just a simple test util which not in the system 'PATH'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `make` variables with `shell` variables. With your setup, the shell command that gets invoked is not influenced by the `make` variable `PATH` that you have set.

You should set the `PATH` variable inside your recipe, like in

```
all:
    @PATH=$(PATH):/opt/bin; cscope --version
```

You have to to both on one line because every line in the recipe will be run in another shell, effectively losing the `PATH` setting that you just did. Or you can divide it over multiple lines by adding a backslash `\` at the end of each line:

```
all:
    @PATH=$(PATH):/opt/bin; \
    cscope --version
```

---

Update

Sorry, I missed the importance of your makefile working with `make 3.82`. I tried with both versions and indeed, `3.81` and `3.82` behave differently in this case.

I did get this to work with `3.81` though by invoking `make` as follows:

```
make SHELL="/bin/sh -c"
```

or

```
make SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. As you way, I have to add "@PATH = $(PATH):/opt/bin" to the command of each target. And the make util build from orignial source hadn't this problem.

Comment: The Makefile in question is a simple example, not the real one used.

Comment: Yes, it works. But 'SHELL=/bin/bash' already in the environment variable can be seen by `env`.

Comment: Thanke you. But I tried make v3.81 build from source, and it works. Then I echo the 'SHELL' internal variable in make, and it is '/bin/sh', both the Xcode's make and build by myself.

Comment: With the help of Reinier Torenbeek, I found the solustion, add the follow line `export SHELL := $(shell echo $$SHELL)` at the head of Makefile. But I don't know the reason yet. Because the internal variable 'SHELL' in program 'make' is '/bin/sh', both in the Xcode's version and build by myself.

Comment: This is weird. I recompiled 3.81 and then it works fine for me as well. The difference in version: the original `make --version` states "This program built for i386-apple-darwin10.0"; the one compiled by myself states "i386-apple-darwin10.8.0".

Comment: Yes, it's so weird. The different in version just the platform of build not the key.

Comment: Looks like some kind of weird bug. I ran into exactly the same problem. Turns out, adding anything "shell-like" to the Makefile line gets shell variables included/exported as expected.
I.e. if you add "yada" to PATH:= then `yada --something` still doesn't work, however `yada "--something"` or `X=1 yada --something` or even `yada --something #comment` does~!!